# When should I use _aligned_malloc()?

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I've been reading the legacy code,which invloves in the customized memory pooling system, then I found that the code uses _aligned_malloc. I wonder what is this function and when do I have to use it.

---

Thanks all of you.

I did read MSDN but what I wanted was the answer like "An example of a reason for wanting a certain alignment is to use the data with the SSE instruction set on x86 where the data must be aligned to a multiple 16".

I finally understood what those code means. thanks again.

Comment: Another example - ARM processor. It requires to align all data to 4 bytes.

Answer (score 12):

This function is useful when the alignment of your memory allocation is important to you.

Alignment means that the numerical value of the pointer returned must be evenly divisible by a certain number, ie. `((unsigned int)ptr) % alignment` should evaluate to 0.

An example of a reason for wanting a certain alignment is to use the data with the SSE instruction set on x86 where the data must be aligned to a multiple 16.

Comment: Or you're trying to store 4 byte longs on a PowerPC (et al)

Answer (score 7):

Here is a use case that you might relate to. In my 17 years of C/C++ development I have only once needed the `_aligned_malloc()` (WinOS implementation) and `memalign` (POSIX implementation) kernel functions, and that was when coding low-level disk I/O. The reason for this is that when not using the OS I/O buffer ( ex. in WinOS calling `openfile()` with the `FILE_FLAG_NO_BUFFERING` flag) and reading/writing to the disk the OS requires the memory block to be aligned to the disk sector size; if the disk sector size was 512 bytes and you wanted to write 1234 bytes to disk I would do something like this:

```
_aligned_malloc(1234, 512);
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked the MSDN documentation?
You can find the respective entry
[here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8z34s9c6(VS.80).aspx).